# Mimirtool - sending data to Grafana

Tags: grafana-alerts, grafana-mimir

I am creating a GitHub action which is going to run mimirtool command and upload alerts into Grafana.

I am trying to send data with mimirtool to my API:

```
mimirtool rules load --address=https://api.mysite.com/mimirtool --id=anonymous --auth-token="<MY TOKEN>" metrics/alerts.yaml
```

(URL address is just for demo purposes)

Once I send the data mimirtool adds a new section to my request by itself. New request URL therefore looks like this:

https://api.mysite.com/mimirtool/prometheus/config/v1/rules/  --> /prometheus/config/v1/rules/  added by mimirtool

This creates errors in therefore the whole request fails.

Is there a way how to disable this additional URL suffix that I am getting ? What would be the correct way to send data to API ?

Mimirtool documentation that I was able to find was not providing any information about this.

> I have tried changing alerts structure to see if data I am trying to send had impact on this error. They don't have impact and file structure is correct - successful request made with postman.